# Select the dataframe based on the certain time value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, timestamp

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A","11:40 AM"],["B","12:51 PM"],["C","6:33 PM"],["D","11:13 AM"],["E","7:13 PM"]],columns=["id","time"])
```

```
id    time
A   11:40 AM
B   12:51 PM
C    6:33 PM
D   11:13 AM
E    7:13 PM
```

I want to select only those rows which are < 6:30 PM.

Expected output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A","11:40 AM"],["B","12:51 PM"],["D","11:13 AM"]],columns=["id","time"])
```

```
id    time
A   11:40 AM
B   12:51 PM
D   11:13 AM
```

I tried `df[(df['time'].dt.time < '18:30:00')]`. It is giving an error. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting to datetime first:

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['time']).le(pd.Timestamp('18:30:00'))]
```

Output:

```
  id      time
0  A  11:40 AM
1  B  12:51 PM
3  D  11:13 AM
```